Solve an integral analytically
I'm trying to show that
$$\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{-\ln (x)}\frac{x}{1-x}dx>\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{-\ln (x)}dx.\quad (E1)$$
But $(E1)$ is equivalent to
$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sqrt{-\ln (x)}}{1-x}dx>2\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{-\ln (x)}dx.\quad (E2)$$
I can show that $\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{-\ln (x)}dx=\sqrt{\pi}/2$. Numerically, $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sqrt{-\ln (x)}}{1-x}dx\approx 2.315$ which is greater than $\sqrt{\pi}$.
Question. Is there a way to prove $(E2)$ analytically?

It's worth noting that all problems of this type can be solved in basically the same way. You're just comparing two computable numbers, so it's possible to compute them to very high accuracy while keeping track of an explicit upper bound on the errors. If you carefully analyze the proofs you used to assert your integrals converge, usually you'll find an explicit mechanism by which you can bound the errors. If the approximations are good enough, then you can straightforwardly decide which is larger by showing the upper bound of one is lesser than the lower bound on the other.

(cont.) Proving strict inequalities between computable numbers is a solved problem, for the reasons I mentioned. There is no trivial strategy for proving exact equalities, however, nor for proving inequalities between non-constant functions.

Write
$$f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{-\log x}}{1-x} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k \sqrt{-\log x}, \quad 0 < x < 1.$$
With the substitution $$x = e^{-u}, \quad dx = -e^{-u} \, du,$$ we obtain
$$\int_{x=0}^1 f(x) \, dx = \int_{u=\infty}^0 \sum_{k=0}^\infty u^{1/2} e^{-ku} (-e^{-u}) \, du = \int_{u=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty u^{1/2} e^{-(k+1)u} \, du.$$
If we can justify interchanging the order of summation and integration, then
$$\begin{align}
\int_{x=0}^1 f(x) \, dx &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \int_{u=0}^\infty u^{1/2} e^{-(k+1)u} \, du \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+1)^{3/2}} \int_{v=0}^\infty v^{1/2} e^{-v} \, dv \\
&= \Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) \sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{-3/2} \\
&= \Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) \zeta\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \zeta\left(\frac{3}{2}\right).
\end{align}$$
Then, what remains is to establish $\zeta(\frac{3}{2}) > 2$.  To do so, we note that by the left endpoint approximation,
$$\zeta\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{-3/2} > \int_{x=1}^\infty x^{-3/2} \, dx = 2.$$

By the monotone convergence theorem (Beppo Levi's lemma) summation and integration can always be interchanged when the summands are nonnegative measurable functions, so it is justified here.

If you just need to prove the inequality, let $x=(1-t^2)$
$$I=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sqrt{-\log (x)}}{1-x}\,dx=2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{ \sqrt{-\log\left(1-t^2\right)}}{t}\,dt$$ Expanding as a series around $t=0$,
$$\frac{ \sqrt{-\log\left(1-t^2\right)}}{t}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {a_n}{b_n}\, t^{2n}$$
where the $a_n$ and $b_n$ respectively correspond to sequences $A272108$ and $A272109$ in $OEIS$ (all of them are positive).
$$I=2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{ \sqrt{-\log\left(1-t^2\right)}}{t}\,dt=2\int_{0}^{1} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {a_n}{b_n}\, t^{2n}\,dt= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2 a_n}{ (2 n+1)\,b_n}$$
Computing the partial sum
$$S_p=\sum_{n=0}^p \frac{2 a_n}{ (2 n+1)\,b_n}$$ generates the sequence
$$\left\{2,\frac{13}{6},\frac{533}{240},\frac{719}{320},\frac{187619}{82944},\frac{3768661}{1658880},\frac{2751865241}{1207664640},\cdots\right\}$$ which are all larger than $\sqrt \pi$.
Edit
Even shorter, if you transform the series into the simplest $[2,2]$ Padé approximant, you can show that
$$\frac{ \sqrt{-\log\left(1-t^2\right)}}{t} > \frac{24-7 t^2}{24-13 t^2}$$
$$\frac{ \sqrt{-\log\left(1-t^2\right)}}{t} - \frac{24-7 t^2}{24-13 t^2}=\frac{41 }{2304}t^6+O\left(t^8\right)$$
$$I=2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{ \sqrt{-\log\left(1-t^2\right)}}{t}\,dt>2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{24-7 t^2}{24-13 t^2}\,dt$$
$$2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{24-7 t^2}{24-13 t^2}\,dt=\frac{2}{169} \left(91+12 \sqrt{78} \coth ^{-1}\left(2 \sqrt{\frac{6}{13}}\right)\right)=2.25796$$
